# "Undefined refrence to"-error while using Conan with Qmake

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake, conan

I tried to use Conan package manager with Qmake in Qtcreator. I followed these tutorials:
[Setting up conan](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-conan.html) and [Conan with QMAKE](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/qmake.html).

I successfully downloaded Poco-library using Conan and even Qtcreator suggested Poco references and functions. So I tried to test if it works with this code:

```cpp
     Poco::MD5Engine md5;
     Poco::DigestOutputStream ds(md5);
     ds << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     ds.close();
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. I got a few errors:

```
error: undefined reference to `Poco::MD5Engine::MD5Engine()'
error: undefined reference to `Poco::DigestOutputStream::DigestOutputStream(Poco::DigestEngine&)'
error: undefined reference to `Poco::DigestOutputStream::close()'
error: undefined reference to `Poco::DigestOutputStream::~DigestOutputStream()'
error: undefined reference to `Poco::MD5Engine::~MD5Engine()'
error: undefined reference to `Poco::DigestOutputStream::~DigestOutputStream()'
error: undefined reference to `Poco::MD5Engine::~MD5Engine()'
```

I think the cause of this problem might be related to linking the libraries but I'm not sure. If this is the case what do I need to do to link libraries correctly?

What causes these errors and how I can get rid of them?

Comment: Q: Conan! What is best in life? A: To crush your enemies, to see them driven before you, and to read Stack Overflow questions with good [mre]s.